# How do I set the acl flag for a file system?

Tags: linux

How do I set the acl flag to persist on mounting a drive in ubuntu linux?

I need to use setfacl.  Do I add it to the /etc/fstab?  What is the format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the ACL flag use this format in /etc/fstab:

```
/dev/sda5   /export/home    ext4    defaults,acl    0   0
```

Just add it as a comma separated entry to the options column.